# Is it possible to make easier this code?

Tags: php

That was a question from interview. This code works, but it is very difficult to maintain. What should be changed in order to make this easier? Thanks for answers!

```
$adSpaceCorrect = !empty($payload->adSpaces) && is_array($payload->adSpaces);
    if ($adSpaceCorrect) {
        if (count($payload->adSpaces)>0){
            foreach($payload->adSpaces as $adSpace) {
                if(!is_string(adSpace)){
                    $dataStatus.='Ad Spaces contains a non-string value.';
                    $adSpaceCorrect=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
                    $dataStatus.='Ad Spaces is an empty array.';
                    $adSpaceCorrect=false;

        }

    }
```

Comment: What did the interviewer ask?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*easier*"? easier to read? easier to maintain? Also, Your title is too common a request to be appropriate for this site. What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question. "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Please read [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @SamOnela - It's evident to me that he's not a native English speaker, maybe he doesn't know a better word than "easy." Also, he's new here, perhaps you could point out the [Edit button](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/184379/edit) and explain that's how he is to update his title to state the function of the code - although, if the code was given to him in an interview he may not know the function of it.

Comment: Yeah I should have included `[edit]` in my comment; actually this code looks like a stub until the other variables are declared/defined here.... which makes this question off-topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The check for `count($payload->adSpaces)>0` is redundant because you already know it's a non-empty array as per `$adSpaceCorrect`.
- Once you correct the nested `if`s it becomes clear that the second `$adSpaceCorrect=false;` is redundant.

> ```
> $adSpaceCorrect = !empty($payload->adSpaces) && is_array($payload->adSpaces);
> if ($adSpaceCorrect) {
>     foreach($payload->adSpaces as $adSpace) {
>         if(!is_string($adSpace)){
>             $dataStatus.='Ad Spaces contains a non-string value.';
>             $adSpaceCorrect=false;
>             break;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: also, there's a typo in `if(!is_string(adSpace)){`

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Thanks for pointing that out!